# Subquery depth needed for selecting `greatest n per group`

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

I have a table with `id`, `name`, `team` & another with `score` for a group of people.

```
Scores                    People       
--------------------      --------------
id  people_id  score      id  name  team                    
1   1          10         1   Sam   A                 
2   1          20         2   Jon   B                 
3   2          5          3   Mat   C                
4   3          15         4   Ted   A                 
5   4          2          5   Tim   A            
6   3          5          ...                               
7   4          7    
...
```

I want to sum the scores for each team, and then rank the scores & get the top 2 rank per team, as done below.

My query has 3 levels of select. **Can I simplify it to 2 levels** by clubbing the clause `WHERE rank_score < 3` in the 2nd select

```
SELECT "id", "name", "team", "rank_score"
FROM
  ( SELECT "id", "name", "team"
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY "team" ORDER BY "count_score" DESC) AS "rank_score"
    FROM 
      (SELECT "id", "name", "team"
       COUNT("score") AS  "count_score"
       FROM "people"
       INNER JOIN "scores" on ("scores"."people_id" = "people"."id")
       GROUP BY "id", "name", "team"
      ) AS "count_table"
  ) AS "rank_table"
WHERE rank_score < 3
```

**Output Desired :**

```
1st SELECT output
-----------------
id  name  team count_score
1   Sam   A    30 
2   Jon   B    5
3   Mat   C    20
4   Ted   A    9
5   Tim   A    0
....

2nd SELECT output
-----------------
id  name  team rank_score
1   Sam   A    1 
2   Jon   B    4
3   Mat   C    2
4   Ted   A    3
5   Tim   A    5
....

3rd SELECT output
-----------------
id  name  team rank_score
1   Sam   A    1 
2   Jon   B    4
3   Mat   C    2
4   Ted   A    3
....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid one level (the order by count(score) can be done in the PARTITION clause).

```
SELECT id, name, team, rank_score
FROM
  ( SELECT p.id, p.name, p.team,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY team ORDER BY count(score) DESC) AS rank_score
    FROM  people p
    JOIN scores s on s.people_id = p.id
    GROUP BY p.id, p.name, p.team
  )  rank_table
WHERE rank_score < 3;
```

see [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1e5e8/21) with your query (corrected) and this one

with a cte (which doesn't change the source of your problem, but may be more readable)

```
with rank_cte as (SELECT p.id, p.name, p.team,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY team ORDER BY count(score) DESC) AS rank_score
    FROM people p
    join scores s on s.people_id = p.id
   group by p.id, p.name, p.team)

select * from rank_cte
where rank_score <3;
```

Comment: I've been searching for this all over (combining row_number & count). Thank you for confirming the exact syntax. Any comment on how much efficient is this than the previous one? I suppose the computation of count requires a full iteration through the rows before ranking can be done with ROW_NUMBER. With that in mind, is it simply less lines of sql code or is it efficient also?

Comment: @click you can look at execution plan (even on sqlfiddle). I would say this version should be a little bit more efficient. Just for completeness : you can't have a WHERE (or HAVING) clause on a ROW_NUMBER at the same level of query. That's why you need at least one level of subquery (or a CTE, which will be changed to a subquery)

Comment: Do I really need to first `ORDER BY` and then assign `ROW_NUMBER` when all I need is top `n` results. Aren't they redundant for my use case. If I already have an ordered table, I can simply pick the top 2 results without assigning a ROW_NUMBER. Is that possible with SQL?

Comment: it depends on your needs. If you only need the 2 players with the highest scores, a TOP 2 query is clearly enoug. If you want top 2 result BY player, than you need this.

Comment: In this query where COUNT is done inside ROW_NUMBER partition, how can I access the COUNT value in my output? Will I have to go back to my 3 step query for that?

Answer (score -1):

You can use a CTE. Here's an example

```
WITH Sales_CTE (SalesPersonID, SalesOrderID, SalesYear)
AS
-- Define the CTE query.
(
    SELECT SalesPersonID, SalesOrderID, YEAR(OrderDate) AS SalesYear
    FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader
    WHERE SalesPersonID IS NOT NULL
)
-- Define the outer query referencing the CTE name.
SELECT SalesPersonID, COUNT(SalesOrderID) AS TotalSales, SalesYear
FROM Sales_CTE
GROUP BY SalesYear, SalesPersonID
ORDER BY SalesPersonID, SalesYear;
```

I'm sure you'd be apply this to your code :)

Edit - Also, you are using count() as far as I know this only counts the number of rows, not the score. You need to use SUM()

Comment: Correct about SUM. Aren't CTE & subquery almost same ? (not talking about recursion)

Comment: The posted SQL has nothing to do with the question (neither the table names match nor what it actually does)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Stackoverflow doesn't exist to do your work for you. I clearly state it's an example of a CTE and that the solution would help the OP get to his/her requirements. Learning things instead of copy/pasting is much more fun and long-term than just waiting for someone to do your job for you

Comment: @click yes they are almost the same, but instead of doing 3 selects like you did, you would need only 2 or even just 1

Comment: I agree that SO is not there to "do the work", but answer should at least somehow relate to the question e.g. by solving the same problem as the question describes or at least by using the names of tables supplied in the question